# Сократить кол-во цифр в PHP

Tags: php

Произвожу вычисление в PHP следующих чисел:
1999 / 15000
На выходе получаю 0.13326666666666667
Как остаток сократить до 6-ти чисел? чтобы на выходе вышло
0.133266

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В PHP Для округления числе можно использовать следующие функции:

- **round** – округление до ближайшего значения;
- **ceil** – округление до ближайшего значения в большую сторону;
- **floor** – округление до ближайшего значения в меньшую сторону.

---

**Пример**

```
$x = 1999 / 15000;
echo round($x, 6);
```

При математическом округлении, учитывается значение числа округляемой части. Если оно меньше 5, округляется к меньшему. Более подробно можно узнать [тут](http://space-base.ru/library/?book=66)

Answer (score 2):

> *Как остаток сократить до 6-ти чисел? чтобы на выходе вышло **0.133266***

Есть ещё пара вариантов - с помощью **number_format()** или с помощью **preg_replace()**. Первый вариант выполняет округление в большую сторону, а второй возвращает необходимое количество цифр, как есть:

```
$int = 0.13326666666666667;
$numb = (float)number_format($int, 6);

var_dump($numb); // float 0.133267


$str = '0.13326666666666667';
$numb = (float)preg_replace('~(\d+\.\d{6})\d*~', '$1', $str);

var_dump($numb); // float 0.133266
```